# MySql Function Creation Error

Tags: mysql, function

I write a function like the following. the purpose of this function is to return the place of a student by some specific exam in a branch.

```
DELIMITER $$    

CREATE FUNCTION `getMerit`( branch VARCHAR(50), totalMark DECIMAL(19,2), comaSeparetedExamIds VARCHAR(200) ) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    SET @comaSeparetedExamIds=comaSeparetedExamIds;
    SET @branch =branch;
    SET @marks=totalMark;

    SELECT @place=COUNT(*)+1
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(m.marks) marks 
        FROM marksheet m, studentinfo s
        WHERE exam_id IN (@comaSeparetedExamIds)
            AND m.student_roll=s.roll_no
            AND s.branch LIKE CONCAT(@branch,'%')
        GROUP BY m.student_roll
    ) AS a
    WHERE a.marks>@totalMark; 

    RETURN @place;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But It shows me an error. the Error is

> Query : CREATE FUNCTION `getMerit`( branch varchar(50), totalMark
>   DECIMAL(19,2), comaSeparetedExamIds varchar(200) ) RETURNS int(11)
>   BEG... Error Code : 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a
>   function

What mistake I made here, Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't name input variables with @. @ is used for [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html), ie connection local variables that don't needs to be declared.

Also you can't have `select`s in functions.

**Procedures** can return result sets but return values.
**Functions** can return values but not result sets.

They also differs in how you use them.

```
select function_name(1) from dual;
select id, name, funcation_name(id, name) from anyTable;

call procedure_name(1);
```

And when assigning variables inside selects you need to do `:=` and not `=`. In your code you are actually selecting true or false and not the count.

This should work.

```
DELIMITER $$    

CREATE FUNCTION `getMerit`( branch VARCHAR(50), totalMark DECIMAL(19,2), comaSeparetedExamIds VARCHAR(200) ) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    SET @comaSeparetedExamIds=comaSeparetedExamIds;
    SET @branch =branch;
    SET @marks=totalMark;

    SELECT COUNT(*)+1 INTO @place
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(m.marks) marks 
        FROM marksheet m, studentinfo s
        WHERE exam_id IN (@comaSeparetedExamIds)
            AND m.student_roll=s.roll_no
            AND s.branch LIKE CONCAT(@branch,'%')
        GROUP BY m.student_roll
    ) AS a
    WHERE a.marks>@totalMark; 

    RETURN @place;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: so, how can i return the count ?
Is there any way to return the count result from this function?

Comment: Try out the suggestion in my answer, this is untested but I've placed the value in @place using `select ... into` and that will suppress the result set from being returned.